# error in maximum number calculation

Tags: php, mysql

patient_id:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

```
 $result2=mysql_query("select max(patient_id) as maximum from outdoor");
        $row2= mysql_fetch_array($result2);
      echo $res=$row2['maximum'];
```

Its taking maximum number as 9 not 10.

Comment: Is your `patient_id` an char or a int column?

Comment: I got the op.. patient_id was in char .. i changed it into int .. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$sql = "select max(CONVERT(patient_id,UNSIGNED INTEGER)) as maximum from outdoor";
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$sql = "select GREATEST(patient_id) as maximum from outdoor";
```

Use [**GREATEST()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)

Eg:

```
SELECT GREATEST(2,1);
```